# Diffie-Hellman Server and Client Mismatch Computed Shared Key

Tags: c#, openssl, diffie-hellman

I am trying to implement a Diffie-Hellman key sharing between Linux (client side) using openssl, and Win 7 (server side) using Mentalis DiffieHellman C# package (downloaded from http://www.mentalis.org)

**Client side:**
    DH *client_key = DH_new();

```
int rc = DH_generate_parameters_ex(client_key, 1024, DH_GENERATOR_2, NULL);

rc = DH_generate_key(client_key) code:

// Example of the client->pub_key (128 bytes):

//"0E9948EB9B589678805A0CCD46FAF6D834478571F9C8046AB67C06B2B091DD63E752B4B48565F87CBED02E1B150064636C36BDFC3
//570CD7EC6D90BC1CEA1AC303F335592286B30BD6D42714EF50C78649A2E5F6C41BD9CE625C2CF20DF89F762253C0954CBFCCDE4ED
//728330C1378545EBE746FB04F4935E2251B17F577C87FE"

int generated_key_length = BN_num_bytes(client_key->pub_key);

unsigned char *share_key = (unsigned char *)calloc(DH_size(client_key));

// Share the client public key to the server

char *pub_key_string = BN_bn2hex(client_key->pub_key);

// Example of the server_pubkey (128 bytes):
//"3D69F1371BAD271518D5D51978CBEBAD463E743F450937600F15037BA9B134F7008065A337DDBACD9C7DE58188F0DCE4D546FA8591
//18A2C791EBABA751A2774E57831A5AE9F3C5FAA192A11AA170EC4B5BF23CF70354A865AA5CDDFCC50A364B6835AA0652C1D498A079
//F994C8004E0FC9C3727EFAAD8AFF7786EDD5B945454F"         

rc = DH_compute_key(share_key, server_pubkey, client_key):

// Example of the computed share_key (128 bytes):
 //"6B1387C957BBC5BE7EFA8B44E2DA2306CBD54838A94EB187532FEFC2EAE0D19EFA42DAA1330F9D32676E986959DC18DC98EBCD1703
//2B2B4B034E88E8270EAB766B0479469E2C1CA2B49D2DB47194D606038958CA683297B1982A571825631B55BCED80B9599DE64D7DA7
//CD7CECDB6D1B522641C95DAA1C859380A3D623515A44"         

free(secret_key);

DH_free(client_key);

// **End of Client side code!**

**Server side (C#) code:**

using Org.Mentalis.Security.Cryptography;

// Create a new DH instance
DiffieHellman dhServer = new DiffieHellmanManaged();

// Generate the public key of the first DH instance
byte[] server_pubkey = dhServer.CreateKeyExchange();
// And, hex encode server_pubkey and send it to the client side

// Decode the hex-encoded client_pubkey to get the share_key
byte[] sharedKey = dhServer.DecryptKeyExchange(client_pubkey); 

// **End of Server side code!**
```

Based on the above implementations, I never success in getting the computed share_keys (one from the client side, 
and the other from the server side) the same! What am I missing or doing wrong?

I would also like to ask whether there is other "c# packages"/methods that can be used at the Server side to do DH key sharing with openssl? Many many thanks.

Comment: You need to use shared parameters. You can't generate the parametrs every time, they had to be the same for client and server.

Comment: Thanks Krasnov, based on your comment I got the solution!